# Error with PaletteGroupBar

Tags: syncfusion

after dragging the PaletteGroupBar onto my webPage i become an Error Message:

```
"Error Rendering Control - Palette GroupBar1 An unhandled exception has occurred. Value 
 does not fall within the expected range".
```

does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: thanx Rachel for ur Editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using Syncfusion products.

We are unable to reproduce the reported issue in our end. Could you please share us more details such as your Essential Studio and .NET framework version which will help us to looking into this further and provide a better solution soon?

Also, you can contact our support team through Direct-Trac and will get a prompt assistance for your query.

http://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac

Thanks,
Syncfusion Team.